# Where do I find the source for the "script" command in linux

Tags: linux

Where do I find the source for the "script" command. I would like to change it from relative time between lines to relative time from start of script?

ie, man script
SCRIPT(1)                 BSD General Commands Manual                SCRIPT(1)
NAME
     script - make typescript of terminal session
SYNOPSIS
     script [-a] [-c COMMAND] [-f] [-q] [-t] [file]

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Copypasted straight from my man page: ftp://ftp.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/util-linux/

Comment: Think before you downvote this everyone. How else could this question be answered without a link to the source?